# Windows Batch - Random Line from Text File

Tags: batch-file

I can't get the following thing working. I have a text file with 400 lines and growing. I need a batch script that picks a single random line form that file.

I tried to modify some code that does the randomization but sometimes it picks a number that is larger than 400 and the script returns an error:

```
set "file=C:\Users\User\Desktop\resolutions.txt"
for /f %%N in ('findstr "." "%file%"^|find /c /v ""') do set lines=%%N
set /a "iterations=%random% %% 1 + 1"

set /a randomfixed = %random% * %Lines% / 32767 + 1

for /f "skip=%randomfixed% tokens=* delims=" %%j IN (C:\Users\User\Desktop\useragents.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
    set var!N!=%%j
)
@echo %var1%
```

I guess there is an easier way to handle this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=1delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "file.txt"') do set /a count=%%i
set /a rd=%random%%%count
if %rd% equ 0 (set "skip=") else set "skip=skip=%rd%"
set "found="
for /f "%skip%tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "file.txt"') do if not defined found set "found=%%i"&set "var=%%j"
echo.random line %found%: %var%
endlocal
```

Comment: What if the file has only 1 line?

Comment: In this case the code does properly echo line #1! But imo nobody needs a random output from a single line file.

Answer (score 1):

`%RANDOM%` returns a random decimal number between 0 and 32767 ...

By substituting in 0 and 32767 into the following *(in the place of %random%)*, this seems to be what you'll need to get values from 1 to 400 inclusive :

`SET /a randomfixed = 1 + (%random% * (400-1) / 32767)`
*(your version gives results from 1 to 401)*