# Batch File: Assign random line of text file as variable for later use

Tags: batch-file, text, random

I'm trying to write a very simple batch file for personal use...It's complete except for one thing I'm stumped on. Hopefully this is an easy fix (I'm effectively illiterate when it comes to code).

Basically what I'm trying to do is have the script choose a random line from a text file, do this a couple times with a couple different text files, then I wish to assign the output from each text file to a variable so that I can easily use them in various combinations...then repeat the process.
Here is what I have right now...

```
@ECHO OFF
:START
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

SET "list1=list1.txt"
FOR /f %%a IN ('type "%list1%"^|find /c /v ""') DO SET /a numlines=%%a
SET /A list1random=(%RANDOM% %% %NumLines%)
IF "%list1random%"=="0" (SET "list1random=") ELSE (SET "list1random=skip=%list1random%")
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* %list1random% delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE %list1%`) DO (
    >> output.txt ECHO %%A
)
:Finish
ENDLOCAL
GOTO START`
```

This procures the random line, and spits it to a text file. All is well, next step, take that random result and assign it to a variable...

```
@ECHO OFF
:START
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

SET "list1=list1.txt"
FOR /f %%a IN ('type "%list1%"^|find /c /v ""') DO SET /a numlines=%%a
SET /A list1random=(%RANDOM% %% %NumLines%)
IF "%list1random%"=="0" (SET "list1random=") ELSE (SET "list1random=skip=%list1random%")
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* %list1random% delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE %list1%`) DO (
    SET output1=%%A
)
>> output.txt ECHO %output1%
:Finish
ENDLOCAL
GOTO START
```

Now the output ceases to be random...instead it is always the last line of the referenced text file.

EDIT: The site suggested another question that was similar to mine. However, that person was having trouble getting the script to choose a valid line. I get a valid line every time, and a random one too (when I check it via echo), but a non-random line when proceeding on, assigning the output to a variable. I don't understand because it seems like a post-facto derandomization. I.E. the difference between the two scripts has nothing to do with procuring the random result, only what to do with that result AFTER it has it, right?

I appreciate any help in advance, this is the last step before I know everything I need to finish this, I'm excited!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch - Random Line from Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617345/windows-batch-random-line-from-text-file)

Comment: `EnableDelayedExpansion` but you don't actually use it. Refer to variables expanded at execution time (rather than when read) with `!var!`. See `setlocal /?` AND also `set /?` for a discussion on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you're right...anyways, I figured out a simple workaround, probably not the quickest in terms of processing time, but whatever. Basically allow the initial part of the script to spit out the random result to a text file (as seemed to work just fine) then reference the text file as a variable.

```
@ECHO OFF
:START
SET "list1=list1.txt"
FOR /f %%a IN ('type "%list1%"^|find /c /v ""') DO SET /a numlines=%%a
SET /A listchoice=(%RANDOM% %% %NumLines%)
IF "%listchoice%"=="0" (SET "listchoice=") ELSE (SET "listchoice=skip=%listchoice%")
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* %listchoice% delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE %list1%`) DO (
>> listoutput.txt ECHO %%A
)
Set /p list=<listoutput.txt
>> result.txt ECHO %list%
:Finish
DEL listoutput.txt
GOTO START
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do in PowerShell using the built-in `Get-Random` cmdlet.

```
 $line = (Get-Content file.txt | where { $_ } | Get-Random)
```

Which makes it also easy in batch.

```
set filename=file.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('powershell -ex bypass -c "gc %filename% | ? { $_ } | Get-Random"') do (
  set "var=%%a"
)
```

*The `where { $_ }` clause is only necessary to filter out any blank lines.  You can omit it if you know your file has none.*